"Associate App with Store" doesn't list apps
I set up products in the Partner Center for msix submission to the Microsoft Store. The names are reserved and I would like to “Associate App with Store” for each product from within Visual Studio. My solutions each have a Windows Application Packaging project included.
When I click Associate App with Store (from the ‘Publish’ menu), under “existing app names” I get the message “There are no app names to select…”.
When I click ‘Refresh’, the message changes to “An unexpected network error occurred. The app list cannot be retrieved.” I’m logged in to Visual Studio 2022 with the same developer login I used in the Partner Center for app submission.

Apparently this is a widespread problem lately. Awaiting investigation by Microsoft - you can monitor: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/cannot-associate-app-with-store/10781321
